# Android SQL Cursor

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I'm using a SQLite database on Android and I need a particular value from the table. I have a `DataBaseHelper` class.

```
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "my_task";
private static final String COL1 = "ID";
private static final String COL2 = "name";
private static final String COL3 = "status";
private static final String COL4 = "rec";
```

I have to get the value of column `rec` for the given `name` (it's either 0 or 1). I have this function to do the task:

```
public Cursor getRec(String task) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String q = "SELECT " + COL4 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL2 + " = ?";

    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(q, new String[] { task });
    return data;
}
```

I don't know how to get the required value from this returned cursor. I'm new to this, so please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `getRec()` returns a `Cursor` and you can call it like:

```
Cursor c = getRec("John");
```

Then you must check if the cursor contains any rows and if it does you can extract the value of the 1st row:

```
String rec;
if (c.moveToFirst()) rec = c.getString(0);
c.close();
```

You can check the value of the variable `rec`:

- if it is `null` then `'John'` was not found in the table
- if it is not `null` then the variable `rec` contains the value of the column `rec` of the table.

I assume that you expect only 1 row as the result of your query.

If you expect more than 1 rows then use a loop that collects all the `rec`s returned in a list:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();
while (c.moveToNext()) {
    list.add(c.getString(0));
}
c.close();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works as expected. I have a doubt, what'll happen if there are two 'John's in the table? It'll get the first one, right? But what should I do if I want the second or the third ones?